# How do I limit the number of columns of a basic table field?

Tags: livecode

I have a basic table field.
I only need three columns but it displays more.
How do I limit it to three?
And how do I set the width of the columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set the tabStops of fld "Data" to 100,0,150,0,0
```

will hide column 2 and 4, 5, 6, ..., n.

If you want to hide the column, set it's width to 0. If the last parameter is 0 then the rest of columns will be not visible, and it'll be missing vertical line of last visible column. If you want vertical line after last field, add additional 0 [set ... to 100,0,200,0,0]

Comment: `set the tabStops of fld "Data" to 200,100,50, 0` gives three columns of the width 200, 100 and 50. Thank you.

Comment: I prefer this answer because I do not need to add up the columns widths and I do not need to be concerned about the width which is used to display the grid.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 600 pixel wide field named "Data" with tab delimited data;

```
set the tabStops of field "Data" to "200,400,600"
```

will set the column widths.  The last tab stop at 600 throws any content beyond the third column outside of the visible area of the field.